# bash not resizing correctly within interactive Docker container

Tags: bash, docker

Every time the terminal size changes, usually `bash` will `resize` automatically so that the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are recomputed correctly. But for some reason this isn't working within a Docker container running `bash` interactively.

I have `shopt checkwinsize -s` in my `bashrc` in the Docker container (and verified that it is `on` using `shopt`). Same with the host `bash` session.

I'm out of ideas, really; `shopt checkwinsize -s` is the only method I have found for getting `bash` to automatically evaluate `resize` when the window is resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your shell is su'd to root, Docker may not succeed in sending signals to it, since that crosses a privilege boundary.  (This is not just a problem with Docker).

Further reading:

- [SIGWINCH attached processes #5736](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5736) , mentions the `su` issue.
- [SIGBJD](https://gist.github.com/rheinwein/3b8f4935c588d5187ce0)
- [Docker attach to curses process](https://serverfault.com/questions/633671/docker-attach-to-curses-process/633727#633727)

Comment: Makes sense. Running `docker run ...` with `sudo` fixes my problem. Thanks!